# Can't open exe in file browser, can in cmd?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Windows 7, 64bit. 
Any idea how it's possible that outlook.exe can be run from an unelevated command line window, but not from windows explorer? Opening from the file browser gives error that Windows can't access the file and permissions might be wrong.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you right-click outlook.exe and click "open". Shell extensions can cause interesting problems sometimes.

Comment: @w32sh same behavior. Turns out iexplore is getting the same error when I try to open it as well.

Comment: @w32sh editflags: 38 07 00 00. FriendlyTypeName: @%systemroot%\system32\shell32.dll,-10156

Comment: I checked and it's not due to file associations as far as I know. Probably a 3rd party shell extension.. think so. Does Run dialog method work?